# Changing Windows registry value in HKEY_USERS with Puppet

Tags: registry, puppet

I'm using Puppet 4.2, and I have got a job where I need to change some values from the registry using the
[Puppet Registry Module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/registry)

I'm trying to change a registry value in the hive `HKEY_USERS`, but I saw that the Puppet module doesn't work over there.
I tried a different approach: changing this value with Powershell, but it does not work with the
[Puppet Powershell Module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/powershell)

This is the code that I run:

```
'$null=New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_USERS  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; Set-ItemProperty -Path $("HKU:\"+$((Get-WmiObject Win32_useraccount) | ?{$_.Name -eq "Administrator"}).SID+"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize") -Name EnableTransparency -Value 0 -Force'
```

If I run it with puppet it doesn't work, and when I run it in the local console it does.

Comment: `HKCU` = `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` - it'll only apply to the hive of the user running puppet

Comment: You are right, I made mistake with the line a copied..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HKEY_USERS is now supported in the unreleased version of puppetlabs/registry (unreleased as of November 2016). I would look for that to become available in a 1.1.4 release of the module on the forge. Until then you can use the GitHub master branch - https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-registry.

For more information, see https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-3865. For managing HKCU, see https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-422.

Comment: Thank you very much!
You saved me!

Comment: @JohnVendor Mark this as the answer if this answered your question. :D